# Which of the following statements regarding quadratic forms in $3$ variables

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Please give a hint for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following theorems will be helpful:

**Theorem(Sylvester's law of inertia)**: Let $\phi$ be a symmetric bilinear form on a finite-dimensional real vector space $V$. Then there exists unique non-negative integers $p$, $q$ such that $\phi$ is represented by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}I_p & 0 & 0\\
0 & -I_q & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
with respect to some basis. Then $p+q=r(\phi)$ is the rank of this bilinear form.

**Theorem**: Let $\phi$ be a symmetric bilinear form over a complex vector space $V$. Then there exists a basis $(\mathbf v_1,\cdots, \mathbf v_m)$ for $V$ such that $\phi$ is represented by
$$\begin{pmatrix}I_p & 0 \\
0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
with respect to this basis, where $p = r(\phi)$ is the rank of this bilinear form.

Also note that the rank of a bilinear form is invariant under isomorphisms. Hope this helps!